# Why doesn't 'mount' use all default options listed in man page?

Tags: linux, mount

I'm trying to mount the partition /dev/sda4 like this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4
```

My /etc/fstab has this line:

```
/dev/sda4 /home/lv/Media ext4 defaults 0 2
```

But still when I use `mount` I get this:

```
/dev/sda4 on /home/lv/Media type ext4 (rw)
```

I read defaults should be equal to rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, async, and relatime. What's the deal with this?

Comment: It depends on OS type, for ex. the default options in Ubuntu Linux are rw,relatime

Comment: Have you tried `mount -v`?

Comment: I just tried changing the options to "auto,rw,exec" and still it only returns rw when I use "mount". EDIT: Also tried "sudo mount -v /dev/sda4" which just returns "mount: /dev/sda4 mounted on /home/lv/Media."

Answer (score 1):

From [fstab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html):

> defaults
>
> use default options: rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async.

I believe, all these options are default behaviour and thus not shown explicitly (one exception is `rw`). If `nosuid` is *not* given, mount defaults to `suid`; if `nodev` is *not* given, mount defaults to `dev`, and so on.

For example, `noexec` option is shown:

```
$ mount /dev/sda1 foo -o noexec
$ ./foo/bin/date 
zsh: permission denied: ./foo/bin/date
$ mount | grep foo
/dev/sda1 on /root/foo type ext4 (rw,noexec)
```

But `exec` option is not:

```
$ mount /dev/sda1 foo -o exec  
$ ./foo/bin/date             
Tue Jul 28 08:58:36 MSK 2015
$ mount | grep foo           
/dev/sda1 on /root/foo type ext4 (rw)
```